# java_home not found on osx mavericks

Tags: java, macos, java-home

Can anyone help me figure out why every command I execute involving 
**JAVA_HOME**
results in

```
-bash: /usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory
```

interestingly when i do an `ls -al` of `/usr/libexec/java_home` is listed as

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     
79 Apr 10 13:15 java_home -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home
```

I am unable to run any java based programs because JDK isn't working.

Comment: Have you checked in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home` that the file is really there?

Comment: Can you try `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and report back here?

Comment: thanks for your help guys. after trying to figure what the issue is i gave up and reinstalled osx mavericks (yeah i know, i code in java so without it the machine is pretty much useless to me) anyways now /usr/libexec/java_home gives me - 1.8.0, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home but android studio and eclipse is still asking me to install jdk 6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions

Comment: Android is unable to work with Java 8, and you need to also install an earlier version of Java. See comment from @JGFMK